# Check if the Microsoft Band device is connected

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-band

I'm working with the Microsoft Band SDK, both for iOS and Windows Phone. I noticed that on iOS I can check if the wearable device is connected to smartphone doing so:

```
MSBClient* bandClient = [[[MSBClientManager sharedManager]attachedClients]firstObject];

if(bandClient.isDeviceConnected){
   //...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result on Windows Phone? I get the bandClient on Windows Phone this way:

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
{
    //stuff...
}
```

But after the connection, how can I understand if the band is, at a certain point, connected to (or disconnected from) the phone? On Windows Phone sdk there's no `onClientDisconnected()` callback and there's no function like `bandClient.isDeviceConnected()`.

Is there a way to check if the Band is connected to the smarthphone? This is really important: after the connection, for instance, I could take my band and go far from the smartphone loosing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows there is no need for an "is connected" method as calling IBandClientManager.ConnectAsync() attempts to establish a Bluetooth connection with the Band (broken only when the returned IBandClient is disposed).  If a connection cannot be made, the method will throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, but how can I understand if the band is, at a certain point, disconnected from the smarthphone? The sdk for Windows Phone hasn't a callback like "onClientDisconnected" and, as I said here above, there's no "client.isDeviceConnected" property (or method). If I establish a connection and then I take my band and I go far from the phone the connection get lost. And I don't know how to understand it. Do I have to make "connection polling" calling the ConnectAsync() every, for example, 10 seconds? It seems really ugly. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: The Windows Phone Band SDK doesn't provide an "on disconnected" callback or event.  If you invoke a method on an IBandClient that does not succeed (say, because the Band went out of range) then the method will throw an exception.  The Band SDK is limited by the underlying platform Bluetooth APIs, which do not always allow it to determine when a Bluetooth device can no longer (or temporarily cannot) be reached.

Your application must be designed to be resilient to temporary connection failures.  At the same time, your application should minimize time with an open connection to the Band.

Comment: I suspected that there was a problem of that nature. It's a little bit frustrating compared with the two other platforms (iOS and Android). Unfortunately my app must be linked with the band constantly. The only thing I can do, as you suggest me, is to detect exceptions thrown by the system and temporarily stop the interaction between my app and the band. Then, every n seconds, I could try to reconnect to the wearable. So, the answer to my question is your second comment just here above. If you copy-paste in the answer box, I'll accept it. Againg, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to one of the sensors and if you haven't got a value for a time period longer than the sensor update period then it's disconnected. E.g. if you subscribe for a heart rate, you should get a value every second. If it's not received for more than a seconds, then it is disconnected. Battery-wise I would use something with longer interval, e.g. temperature - 30 seconds.
You mentioned that you need constant connection. So maybe you need some of the sensors anyway.